# Need to increase numbers with 1 number when the number have a decimal

Tags: sql-server

I have these numbers (1.6 , 2.3 , 4.5 , 6.1 ) in column hours , what I need exactly :

- Convert (1.6 ) to be 2 , (2.3) to be 3 , (4.5) to be 5 and (6.1) to be 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server function you are looking for is

> CEILING

```
SELECT CEILING(1.6) AS ceiling_value;
-- Result: 2

SELECT CEILING(2.3) AS ceiling_value;
-- Result: 3

SELECT CEILING(4.5) AS ceiling_value;
-- Result: 5

SELECT CEILING(6.1) AS ceiling_value;
-- Result: 7
```

For more info see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: This is the right answer thanks for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL `CEILING` function. This function takes in a number and rounds it up, which is exactly the functionality that you want.

```sql
SELECT CEILING(nums) FROM table;
```

You can also use `CEIL`, which is the same thing, but isn't supported on every platform.

Comment: sql server doesn't have a function called `CEIL`

Comment: As this question is tagged SQL Server it is irrelevant what other platforms support